# Are the following real numbers constructible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

1) $\sqrt[4]{5+\sqrt2}$

2)$\sqrt[6]{2}$

3) $3/(4+\sqrt13)$

4) $3+\sqrt[5]{8}$

From what I know, a number is constructible if it can be converted in a finite number of steps using only the operations addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square roots.

This in mind, I would think #1 is constructible number because it is calculated using addition and square roots, with the 4th being a square root of a square root.

I would say #2 is not constructible as it is not possible to take a third root.

I would say #3 is constructible because it makes use of the addition, division, and square root operations.

Finally, #4 I would say is not constructible because it is not possible to generate the 5th root.

Can anyone weigh in on whether these conjectures are correct/incorrect, or maybe comment on the rationale and whether this method (if correct) could still be used on harder examples?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

A number is constructible iff it is belongs to a field that is $\mathbb{Q}$ or which is the result of finitely many quadratic extensions thereof. If you think of the extended field $\mathbb{k}$ as a vector space over the other field $\mathbb{F}$ (so, I mean the vector space $\mathbb{k}$/$\mathbb{F}$), the extension of $\mathbb{F}$ to $\mathbb{k}$ is quadratic (id est: of degree 2) if $\operatorname{dim}_\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{k}) = 2$.

Consider $\mathbb{k} = \mathbb{Q}(r^{1/3})$, $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{Q}$. Any element of this field $\mathbb{k}$ has the form $q_0 + q_1 r^{1/3} + q_2 r^{2/3}$ where $q_0, q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Thus, we can define a vector $q = (q_0, q_1, q_2) \in \mathbb{Q} \times (r^{1/3}\mathbb{Q}) \times (r^{2/3}\mathbb{Q})$ that encodes isomorphically the information for any element of $\mathbb{k}$. It should be easy to convince yourself that, over $\mathbb{F}$, $\mathbb{k}$ (treated as a vector space) has bases of three vectors. Thus, the extension of $\mathbb{F}$ to $\mathbb{k}$ is NOT quadratic. But that relies on the fact that $r$ be cube-free; if $r$ is a cube, then such an adjoining is not going to be an extension at all, for example.

Note: any quadratic extension of a field of constructible numbers is a field of constructible numbers.
Also note: These must be *field extensions*. Therefore, be careful with what you attempt to adjoin.

Answer (score 2):

I think that
all your answers are correct
for the reasons stated.

The only quibble I might have
is for the non-constructible ones,
where the particular numbers are
non-constructible,
while,
for example,
$\sqrt[3]{8}$
is obviously constructible.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Since the cube root of 8, for example can be reduced to an integer, would the reasoning I stated above hold if we reduced any of the powers > 2 to be expressed in lowest possible terms, if possible, so the only powers left > 2 would then rule out being constructible?

Comment: It *does* turn out that $\sqrt[6]{2}$ and $\sqrt[5]{8}$ are non-constructible, but the proofs are not easy (at least for me). The proof for $\sqrt[6]{2}$ follows from the fact that $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is not constructible, but the proof for $\sqrt[5]{8}$ requires stronger stuff.

Answer (score 1):

While all these answers are correct, just having a root higher than the square root does not guarantee a failure of constructibility.  The number $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt5}\approx 1.618$ (big hint there) has been known to be constructible since Euclid, even if he would not have recognized the number in that form.

Suppose we are given a number $\sqrt[n]{a+\sqrt{b}}$, where $n$ is an odd natural number, $a$ is any integer and $b$ is any positive integer.  We can check such a number for constructibility with a two-step process.

First, if $\sqrt[n]{a+\sqrt{b}}$ is to be constructible then so is the conjugate $\sqrt[n]{a-\sqrt{b}}$.  Thus so is their product $\sqrt[n]{a^2-b}$ and thus, $a^2-b$ must be an $n$th power.  If this passes, define $\sqrt[n]{a^2-b}=R$ and move on to step 2.

In step 2, propose that

$(x+\sqrt{x^2-R})^n=a+\sqrt{b}.$

We also have the conjugate relation:

$(x-\sqrt{x^2-R})^n=a-\sqrt{b}.$

Clearly their product matches up with our defining equation $R^n=a^2-b$.  If you now expand the left sides by the binomial theorem and average the two results, the radicals cancel and you are left with

$x^n+(\frac{n(n-1)}{2})(x^2-R)x^{n-2}+(\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24})(x^2-R)^2x^{n-4}+...+n(x^2-R)^{(n-1)/2}x=a$

If this has a rational root for $x$, then that rational root may be substituted for $x$ and we then have $x+\sqrt{x^2-R}$ as a constructible $n$th root of $a+\sqrt{b}$.  Failure at either this step or step 1, above, means the numbervis not constructible.

Plug in $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt5}$ and see what happens.  First off $2^2-5=-1$ is a perfect cube, and accordingly we will set $R=-1$ for step 2.

For step 2, with a cube root the binomial expansion after canceling radicals will generate two terns, to wit:

$x^3+3(x^2+1)=2$

$4x^3+3x-2=0$

We seek a rational root, using the Rational Root Theorem to identify candidates.  In this case $x=1/2$ succeeds, thus our cube root is constructible and  we identify what we might have suspected from that decimal approximation quoted above:

$\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt5}=(1/2)+\sqrt{(1/2)^2+1}=(1+\sqrt5)/2.$